# Parsing and loading EC Private key, curve secp256r1

Tags: java, key

I'm doing a spin-off request from this: [EC Key request](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/260145/what-format-is-this-private-key-in-and-how-can-i-process-it-using-bouncycastle/266785?noredirect=1#comment566137_266785)

As my problem is a bit different but similar.
I have the following private key (in this format, not a file):
`MHcCAQEEID0VR/I814rQUqWIYPEhno+3kexN/jN2n1ub+mJ6ZWyhoAoGCCqGSM49AwEHoUQDQgAEwKMBv29ByaSLiGF0FctuyB+Hs2oZ1kDIYhTVllPexNGudAlm8IWOH0e+Exc97/zBdawu7Yl+XytQONszGzAK7w==`

And I want to load it to an ECPrivateKey (possibly to have an ECPublicKey too).
Following a bunch of links and ideas, i got two possible code hints:
1- Bouncy castle:

```
val privateKey = "PRIVATE KEY ABOVE, MHc..."
val rdr = StringReader(privateKey)
val parsed = PEMParser(rdr).readObject()
val pair = JcaPEMKeyConverter().getKeyPair(parsed as PEMKeyPair)
println("[load_ec_pair_keys] Algorithm: ${pair.private.algorithm} , Private Key: ${pair.private} , Public Key: ${pair.public}")
return pair
```

The output gives:

> Algorithm: ECDSA , Private Key: EC Private Key >[fe:60:f6:24:f9:ba:61:4f:60:98:d9:72:b2:14:87:c8:13:c2:3f:f4]
>
> X: c0a301bf6f41c9a48b88617415cb6ec81f87b36a19d640c86214d59653dec4d1
>
> Y: ae740966f0858e1f47be13173deffcc175ac2eed897e5f2b5038db331b300aef

But if I save that private key to a pem file and use openssl:
**openssl ec -noout -text -inform PEM -in private.pem**
The result is:

> read EC key
> Private-Key: (256 bit)
>
> priv:
> 3d:15:47:f2:3c:d7:8a:d0:52:a5:88:60:f1:21:9e:
> 8f:b7:91:ec:4d:fe:33:76:9f:5b:9b:fa:62:7a:65:
> 6c:a1
>
> pub:
> 04:c0:a3:01:bf:6f:41:c9:a4:8b:88:61:74:15:cb:
> 6e:c8:1f:87:b3:6a:19:d6:40:c8:62:14:d5:96:53:
> de:c4:d1:ae:74:09:66:f0:85:8e:1f:47:be:13:17:
> 3d:ef:fc:c1:75:ac:2e:ed:89:7e:5f:2b:50:38:db:
> 33:1b:30:0a:ef
>
> ASN1 OID: prime256v1
>
> NIST CURVE: P-256

So those seems different to me, and using the help (see comments too) of @dave_thompson_085 I ended up with the following code:
2 - No BouncyCastle, java.security package:

```
fun load_ec_full(): ECPrivateKey {
        val a = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("EC")
        a.init(ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
        val p: ECParameterSpec = a.getParameterSpec(ECParameterSpec::class.java)
        println("p=(dec)" + (p.curve.field as ECFieldFp).p)
        val G: ECPoint = p.generator
        System.out.format("Gx=(hex)%032x%n", G.affineX)
        System.out.format("Gy=(hex)%032x%n", G.affineY)

//        val headerPrefix = Hex.decode("303E020100301006072A8648CE3D020106052B8104000A042730250201010420") //secp256k1 
        val headerPrefix = Hex.decode("308187020100301306072a8648ce3d020106082a8648ce3d030107046d306b02") //secp256r1 
        val privateKSimple =
            "MHcCAQEEID0VR/I814rQUqWIYPEhno+3kexN/jN2n1ub+mJ6ZWyhoAoGCCqGSM49AwEHoUQDQgAEwKMBv29ByaSLiGF0FctuyB+Hs2oZ1kDIYhTVllPexNGudAlm8IWO" +
                    "H0e+Exc97/zBdawu7Yl+XytQONszGzAK7w=="
        val decodedPK = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKSimple)
        val kf: KeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")
        val k1 = kf.generatePrivate(PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(headerPrefix + decodedPK)) as ECPrivateKey
        val p2 = k1.params
        println("again p=(dec)" + (p2.curve.field as ECFieldFp).p)
        println("KEY: $k1")
```

If i use the first headerPrefix (secp256k1) i got a key with output:

> p=(dec)115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853951
>
> Gx=(hex)6b17d1f2e12c4247f8bce6e563a440f277037d812deb33a0f4a13945d898c296
>
> Gy=(hex)4fe342e2fe1a7f9b8ee7eb4a7c0f9e162bce33576b315ececbb6406837bf51f5
>
> again p=(dec)115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
>
> KEY: sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl@b8485def

So the key is not written out, but is different for the one generated above).

If I use the headerPrefix generated using the openssl command hinted in the other response: **openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in private.pem -out pkcs8der -outform der**
that i obtained as: "308187020100301306072a8648ce3d020106082a8648ce3d030107046d306b02"
this breaks the code:

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid EC private key
> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid EC private key
> at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
> at com.mhamdaoui.smartcardreader.ExampleUnitTest.load_ec_full(ExampleUnitTest.kt:249)
> at com.mhamdaoui.smartcardreader.ExampleUnitTest.test load rsa key(ExampleUnitTest.kt:273)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:55)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
> at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:100)
> at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:107)
> at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:41)
> at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:108)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:40)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:60)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
> at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
> at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
> at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
> Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid EC private key
> at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl.parseKeyBits(Unknown Source)
> at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl.(Unknown Source)
> at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECKeyFactory.implGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
> ... 52 more
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Integer exceeds maximum valid value
> at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.getIntegerInternal(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.getInteger(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getInteger(Unknown Source)
> ... 55 more

I'm quite lost now as I'm new on the field, and honestly this is only a small side of my project.
The only thing I know is that in oder to be sure the key is parsed correctly, the following code on the key should give the result: "c0b77375"

```
val xCoord = privateKey.params.generator.affineX
val calculateSha256 = VASUtils.calculateSha256(xCoord.toByteArray())
val result = calculateSha256.copyOfRange(0, 4)
```

To give you a bit more context, I'm trying to replicate on Android (Kotlin, but is JVM...) the AppleVAS reading code that can be found here:
https://github.com/RfidResearchGroup/proxmark3/blob/32f892e512d97be402c0abaf6f00675686ed0893/client/src/cmdhfvas.c#L280

I have the correct *cryptogram* data and other variables, but method **GetPrivateKeyHint** in Java fails for me and the given key.

If someone can help me, or can check what I'm doing wrong it would be very helpful, I'm planning to put all my work on a github open repository at the end, so it's not a commercial action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of digging into it, I found the solution.
The key retrieval was ok (I improved a bit, see below the code), but the real issue was that I had to use the public affineX (not from private key) and that value must be converted to an unsignedByteArray. That gave me the correct sha256 and the key was obtained correctly without any header needed.

Provide the *privateKey* param as the full Private key String (as in PEM file):

```kt
fun load_pkcs_ec_key_pairs(privateKey: String): Pair<ECPublicKey, ECPrivateKey> {
        StringReader(privateKey).use { keyReader ->
            val pemParser = PEMParser(keyReader)
            val converter = JcaPEMKeyConverter()
            val pemPair = pemParser.readObject() as PEMKeyPair
            val privateKeyInfo = PrivateKeyInfo.getInstance(pemPair.privateKeyInfo)
            val publicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(pemPair.publicKeyInfo)
            val ecpublicKey = converter.getPublicKey(publicKeyInfo) as ECPublicKey
            val ecprivateKey=  converter.getPrivateKey(privateKeyInfo) as ECPrivateKey
            return Pair(ecpublicKey, ecprivateKey)
        }
    }
```

Then use the pair obtained in this way:

```kt
        val privateKey = pairKeys.second
        val publicKey = pairKeys.first

        val xCoord = publicKey.w.affineX
        val reversedX = Utils.toByteArrayUnsigned(xCoord)
        val calculateSha256 = VASUtils.calculateSha256(reversedX)
        val hint = calculateSha256.copyOfRange(0, 4)
        println("[decrypt] Hint calculated is: ${Hex.toHexString(hint)} device: $expected")
        assertEquals(Hex.toHexString(hint), expected)
```

where

```kt
fun toByteArrayUnsigned(bi: BigInteger): ByteArray {
    var extractedBytes = bi.toByteArray()
    var skipped = 0
    var skip = true
    for (b in extractedBytes) {
        val signByte = b == 0x00.toByte()
        if (skip && signByte) {
            skipped++
             continue
        } else if (skip) {
            skip = false
        }
     }
     extractedBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(
         extractedBytes, skipped, extractedBytes.size
     )
     return extractedBytes
}
```